# Apple Code causes overuse of memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I borrowed a piece of code from Apple's site but for some reason the code seems unstable. I have one single UIImageView and I set the UIImage of it like 30 times and it brings the memory up to 250 MB! I think it has to do something with a pointer not being freed but I didn't really know because everywhere I see this code I only here how it works and not about the memory it uses:

```
- (UIImage *)applyBlurWithRadius:(CGFloat)blurRadius tintColor:(UIColor *)tintColor saturationDeltaFactor:(CGFloat)saturationDeltaFactor maskImage:(UIImage *)maskImage
{
    // check pre-conditions
    if (self.size.width < 1 || self.size.height < 1) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: invalid size: (%.2f x %.2f). Both dimensions must be >= 1: %@", self.size.width, self.size.height, self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (!self.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: image must be backed by a CGImage: %@", self);
        return nil;
    }
    if (maskImage && !maskImage.CGImage) {
        NSLog (@"*** error: maskImage must be backed by a CGImage: %@", maskImage);
        return nil;
    }

    CGRect imageRect = { CGPointZero, self.size };
    UIImage *effectImage = self;

    BOOL hasBlur = blurRadius > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    BOOL hasSaturationChange = fabs(saturationDeltaFactor - 1.) > __FLT_EPSILON__;
    if (hasBlur || hasSaturationChange) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectInContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextScaleCTM(effectInContext, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(effectInContext, 0, -self.size.height);
        CGContextDrawImage(effectInContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

        vImage_Buffer effectInBuffer;
        effectInBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectInContext);
        effectInBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectInContext);

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
        CGContextRef effectOutContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        vImage_Buffer effectOutBuffer;
        effectOutBuffer.data     = CGBitmapContextGetData(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.width    = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.height   = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(effectOutContext);
        effectOutBuffer.rowBytes = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(effectOutContext);

        if (hasBlur) {
            // A description of how to compute the box kernel width from the Gaussian
            // radius (aka standard deviation) appears in the SVG spec:
            // http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feGaussianBlurElement
            // 
            // For larger values of 's' (s >= 2.0), an approximation can be used: Three
            // successive box-blurs build a piece-wise quadratic convolution kernel, which
            // approximates the Gaussian kernel to within roughly 3%.
            //
            // let d = floor(s * 3*sqrt(2*pi)/4 + 0.5)
            // 
            // ... if d is odd, use three box-blurs of size 'd', centered on the output pixel.
            // 
            CGFloat inputRadius = blurRadius * [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            NSUInteger radius = floor(inputRadius * 3. * sqrt(2 * M_PI) / 4 + 0.5);
            if (radius % 2 != 1) {
                radius += 1; // force radius to be odd so that the three box-blur methodology works.
            }
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
            vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, NULL, 0, 0, radius, radius, 0, kvImageEdgeExtend);
        }
        BOOL effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = NO;
        if (hasSaturationChange) {
            CGFloat s = saturationDeltaFactor;
            CGFloat floatingPointSaturationMatrix[] = {
                0.0722 + 0.9278 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0.0722 - 0.0722 * s,  0,
                0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0.7152 + 0.2848 * s,  0.7152 - 0.7152 * s,  0,
                0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 - 0.2126 * s,  0.2126 + 0.7873 * s,  0,
                                  0,                    0,                    0,  1,
            };
            const int32_t divisor = 256;
            NSUInteger matrixSize = sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix)/sizeof(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[0]);
            int16_t saturationMatrix[matrixSize];
            for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < matrixSize; ++i) {
                saturationMatrix[i] = (int16_t)roundf(floatingPointSaturationMatrix[i] * divisor);
            }
            if (hasBlur) {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectOutBuffer, &effectInBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
                effectImageBuffersAreSwapped = YES;
            }
            else {
                vImageMatrixMultiply_ARGB8888(&effectInBuffer, &effectOutBuffer, saturationMatrix, divisor, NULL, NULL, kvImageNoFlags);
            }
        }
        if (!effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if (effectImageBuffersAreSwapped)
            effectImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    // set up output context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    CGContextRef outputContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(outputContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(outputContext, 0, -self.size.height);

    // draw base image
    CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, self.CGImage);

    // draw effect image
    if (hasBlur) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        if (maskImage) {
            CGContextClipToMask(outputContext, imageRect, maskImage.CGImage);
        }
        CGContextDrawImage(outputContext, imageRect, effectImage.CGImage);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }

    // add in color tint
    if (tintColor) {
        CGContextSaveGState(outputContext);
        CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(outputContext, tintColor.CGColor);
        CGContextFillRect(outputContext, imageRect);
        CGContextRestoreGState(outputContext);
    }



    // output image is ready
    UIImage *outputImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return outputImage;
}
```

I originally call:

```
UIImage *artwork = [[[Player sharedInstance] currentSong] artwork];
artwork = [artwork applyDarkEffect];
[AppDelegate del].posterBlur.image = artwork; //posterBlur is a global background added to the UIWindow
```

Every call to this function wastes like 6 MB:
[image]

Comment: In the backtrace for each of these leaked objects, which line(s) of code is it in your `-applyBlurWithRadius:...` method that are leaking?

Comment: How do you "set the UIImage of it like 30 times"? Are you aware there's a cache for images loaded from disk. Forcing it to use zero bytes just to make a nicer profiling graph would be supremely inefficient.

Comment: The update is not nearly enough, all it did is raised a new question of what the implementation of `applyDarkEffect` is, it did't answer any of the existing questions.